# Multiple hibernate configurations for multiple War applications in JBoss

Tags: java, hibernate, war, jboss6.x

I have JBoss AS 6 running.

- I have deployed multiple War applications. All those apps access the DB through hibernate configuration.
- I have configured Datasources in JBoss, one DS for each War application, because they use different DB user accounts. Then in each app, I configure the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and state the corresponding DS to be used. Each war has its own `hibernate.cfg.xml`.
- When isolated, each app works perfectly. I start the server, test the app, shutdown the server. All is ok.
- The problems arose when I started the server and started using all the apps.
  The first app to make a connection to the DB seems to work fine, but the following might show some problems related to:

  1. Non-existing hibernate entity mappings.
  2. Non-existing DB tables.

**My theories:**

1. The corresponding `hibernate.cfg.xml` wasn't loaded and the mappings' locations weren't loaded. When a query is performed, hibernate has no knowledge of such entity.
2. The corresponding `hibernate.cfg.xml` wasn't loaded and a different user account is being used to connect to DB. Some tables are only visible to some users.

My question is:

*Why aren't the applications loading correctly the corresponding* `hibernate.cfg.xml`*?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why using the cfg.xml files isn't working, but most of the JBoss/Hibernate apps I see these days use JPA.  If you don't get an answer, maybe try that out?  It's pretty easy, just add a persistence.xml to the META-INF folder that looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/myDB</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mydomain.service.entities.Entity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

You can address the persistence multiple ways, but this works:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyService");
```

Not suggesting you can't get this working with the config file, just offering an alternative...